# How to flatten an ArrayBuffer in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is the sample piece of code. I am using an array of RDDS to store objects. I would like to use flatMap on this array of RDDS and store that into a dataframe.

```
var ArrayofRDDs: ArrayBuffer[T] = null
for(i <- 1 to 10) {
  val data = <A function that returns an object of type T>
  ArrayofRDDs :+ data
}
```

Can someone help with how to use flatMap on the Array of RDDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to use flatMap on the Array of RDDs

Simply don't. RDDs are not `GenTraversableOnce` and cannot be converted to one without using some variant of `collect`. If you want to combine multiple RDDs just use `SparkContext.union`.